# reliability of the properties that are displayed in BIM360 when I work with links

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I ran into a weird problem-
The problem is with the aps viewer which also occurs in the BIM360 viewer

I have a host model and a model loaded into it in Attachment.
When I open the host model in BIM360 the information in the properties of the elements does not match their geometry, but in Revit the information in the properties matches the geometry.
[element for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4516u.jpg)

When I directly open the model in BIM360 (not through the host model) the information in the properties matches the geometry.
[element for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eZtr.jpg)

I reloaded the link, and I also reloaded from, I changed the link to overlay (each time I republished) but none of that helped.

Thanks in advance to the helpers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the heads up. This looks like a potential bug in our conversion pipeline for aggregated Revit designs. If you could share these two files with us via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially - the data would not be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk), we'd be happy to investigate the issue on our side.